# Using "dynamic" type gives a compilation error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, compiler-errors

I want to create a list of anonymous objects. So I did this:

```
var problematicAddresses = new HashSet<dynamic>();
foreach (DataRow row in dtMeters.Rows)
{
    var billingAddress = new
    {
        address = row["BillingAddress"].ToString(),
        city = row["BillingCity"].ToString(),
        state = row["BillingState"].ToString(),
        zip = row["BillingZip"].ToString()
    };    

    // ... fill problematicAddresses without any problem

    foreach (var completeAddress in problematicAddresses)
    {
        string addr = completeAddress.address;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

The last line here doesn't compile and gives me the following error:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: It literally tells you the problem and the solution right in the error message.

Comment: @sll His `HashSet` is of `dynamic` types.

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: To clarify: that's not a rhetorical question. Since the error message is telling you both what is wrong and how to fix it, there must be something unclear in the error message, otherwise you wouldn't be asking for help here. What is unclear?

Comment: Never mind. I just didn't think I needed to add reference to something to use dynamic. It seemed to me like adding reference to use "string" or any other commonly used type. I thought I was missing something else.

Comment: @DavidShochet: But... you *do* need to add a reference to a library to use System.String; its enormous pile of metadata doesn't magically appear out of nowhere!  You need to add a reference to a library for *every* type you use that isn't defined in the program text itself.

Comment: @EricLippert But the need to have a reference in order to use System.String is for the most part *not* met by requiring the user to add that reference; rather, it is usually met by the C# compiler's default behavior of including a reference to mscorlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have those libs included ... Also, use var instead of string on the last line

Comment: Why are you recommending to use `var` on the last line? That would make `addr` `dynamic`, which seems to be not what is wanted.